# Printing json data in javascript function replace quotes by "&quot;"

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm using Laravel Framework since a couple of weeks now.

I have a strange problem, I would like to convert a PHP 2D array into a JavaScript object, so I used in my controller json_encode() something like :

```
$arr['ping']    = array_values($arr['ping']);
$arr['doc']     = array_values($arr['doc']);

$data = json_encode($arr, JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

Then, in my view file :

```
<div class="card-content">
        {{ $data }}
</div>

<div id="chartPingListExpand" class="ct-chart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        app.initChartPingListExpand({{ html_entity_decode($data) }}, {{ $maxping }});
    });
</script>
```

Here is the thing : My `{{ $data }}` shows correctly my json string

```
{"ping":[4,30],"doc":["2018-03-23 09:06:53","2018-03-23 01:04:23"]}
```

But Javascript doesn't like it :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

at this line

```
app.initChartPingListExpand({{ html_entity_decode($data) }}, {{ $maxping }});
```

And I think it's because HTML is translating `quotes` by `&quot ;`
I've tried many ways to tell the html not to translate those quotes but it does not work, anybody has any idea ?

Maybe I can pass data to my Javascript function or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Blade will try to protect you and will escape all unsafe characters. 
use

```
{!! $data !!}
```

to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Your `$data` is already a javascript object, you don't need to decode it

You can try if you put `var obj = {{ $data }}; console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: Thanks for you answer however by putting this i still get this error in the console : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSON.stringify` which converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string

```
var data = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

Please visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however by using console.log() on my stringified string i get this result : "{&quot;ping&quot;:[20,20,45],&quot;doc&quot;:[&quot;2018-03-23 10:10:37&quot;,&quot;2018-03-23 09:06:53&quot;,&quot;2018-03-23 01:04:23&quot;]}"